xscreensaver-demo does not list the hacks in rss-glx package
I have installed the rss-glx package in my Suse Tumbleweed system, and I can see the binaries in /usr/bin/ (the binaries work flawlessly), the symbolic links from /usr/lib64/xscreensaver/ to the binaries, and the corresponding XML files in /etc/xscreensaver/.
What I don't see are the new hacks in the list provided to me by xscreensaver-demo!
Here it is one of those XML files
$ cat /etc/xscreensaver/pixelcity.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<screensaver name="pixelcity" _label="Pixel City">

  <command arg="-r"/>

  <select id="01">
    <option id="01A" _label="Effect Bloom"/>
    <option id="01B" _label="Effect Bloom Radial" arg-set="-B"/>
    <option id="01C" _label="Effect Glass" arg-set="-g"/>
    <option id="01D" _label="Effect Color Cycle" arg-set="-c"/>
    <option id="01E" _label="Effect None" arg-set="-n"/>
  </select>

  <boolean id="02" _label="Wire frame" arg-set="-w"/>

  <boolean id="03" _label="No fog" arg-set="-F"/>

  <boolean id="04" _label="Letter box" arg-set="-l"/>

  <_description>
Procedural city fly through.

Written by Shamus Young &lt;shamus -at- shamusyoung dot com&gt;.
Ported to Linux by Tugrul Galatali - &lt;http://rss-glx.sourceforge.net/&gt;.
  </_description>
</screensaver>

and the associated paths in the binaries directories
/usr/bin/rss-glx-pixelcity
/usr/lib64/xscreensaver/rss-glx-pixelcity

I can see two issues,

no reference to the actual binary name in the XML file
the symbolic links to rss-glx binaries are in /usr/lib64/xscreensaver/ but XScreensaver binaries are in a different place, /usr/libexec/xscreensaver/.

I don't know what to do, what should I do?
